# Concat two lists definition with fold

Tags: haskell, concatenation, fold

I want to make `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` with a fold.
I made this:

```
plusplus :: [a]->[a]->[a]
plusplus l = foldr (\x l1 -> x:l1) l
```

But i am getting the reverser order. E.g:

```
plusplus [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
Output: [4,5,6,1,2,3]
```

I understand why i am geting this, but i still don't know how to fix this.

Edit: I posted the wrong solution, sorry.

Comment: It's doesn't make a lot of sense to define a `++`-like operator using `fold` if the fold uses `++`.

Comment: For a simple fix, you could try the 'other' fold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong `fold` for what you want to do.

Take a look at [wiki haskell's page on foldr, foldl, and foldl'](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl').

`foldr` puts the first argument at the end (think of it as on the "right")
`foldl` puts the first argument logically at the beginning (think of it as on the "left")

When you think of the different fold's like this their names become much more clear. It is simply fold-right and fold-left!

So to get the orders correct use:

```
plusplus :: [a]->[a]->[a] 
plusplus l = foldl (\x l1 -> x:l1) l
```

Answer (score 7):

We start from your wrong code:

```
plusplus :: [a]->[a]->[a]
plusplus l = foldr (\x l1 -> x:l1) l
```

We eta-expand so to mention the second argument:

```
plusplus :: [a]->[a]->[a]
plusplus xs ys = foldr (\x l1 -> x:l1) xs ys
```

This appends in the reverse order, so we flip the arguments to fix it:

```
plusplus :: [a]->[a]->[a]
plusplus xs ys = foldr (\x l1 -> x:l1) ys xs
```

Further finishing touches:

```
plusplus :: [a]->[a]->[a]
plusplus xs ys = foldr (:) ys xs


plusplus :: [a]->[a]->[a]
plusplus xs ys = flip (foldr (:)) xs ys


plusplus :: [a]->[a]->[a]
plusplus = flip (foldr (:))
```

The last one is a tad cryptic, but not excessively so.

My own preferred variant is the pointful `foldr (:) ys xs`, which can be read as follows. Take `xs`, replace every `(:)` in it with `(:)` (no-op), and replace the final `[]` with `ys`.

Comment: The last line is super helpful!